# Elasticsearch Memory Usage Problem in Docker Container

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch, memory, heap-memory

I have a problem about memory usage of elasticsearch. In my system, `60000 documents` are written to the database `per hour`.

But memory usage is constantly increasing over time. I don't understand why it is always increasing. Elasticsearch container ram capacity is `10GB` and `heapsize 5GB for JVM`. I suspect that caches are kept in memory, but I have not encountered an abnormal situation in elastic search configuration settings. I check this query: `GET /_stats`

After a certain period, memory usage of container becomes `100%` and elasticsearch can't response any query.

I would be very pleased if you can help me.